# pyopencl, no matching devices found

Tags: opencl, pyopencl

I am trying to learn pyopencl, but I ran into issues already in the following very simple code:

```
import pyopencl as cl

platform = cl.get_platforms()

my_devices = platform[0].get_devices()
print(my_devices)
```

However, this returns an empty list, while as I understand it it should give my a list containing an object corresponding to my graphics card. How do I troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I had to install drivers(?) for my graphics card that made it available for opencl (which was not mentioned anywhere when installing pyopencl). For the Intel graphics card on linux, there is the open source implementation Beignet, which works fine.